# how would fade an image out and fade another image in that has text?

Tags: css, tumblr, fadein, fadeout

I'm relatively new at coding and I'm trying to make it so one image fades to a different image and that image has text over it.

I'm using Tumblr, so PHP-5-only MVC I'm pretty sure. 
And here's what I have so far:

```html
<style>
  #imagefade {
    background-image: url('http://i65.tinypic.com/107kqbq.jpg');
    position: absolute;
  }
  #imagefade img {
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1.5s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 1.5s;
    -o-transition: all ease 1.5s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 1.5s;
    transition: all ease 1.5s;
  }
  #imagefade img:hover {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  #text {
    position: center;
  }
  .image {
    position: relative;
  }
  p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 38px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
  }
</style>

<div id="imagefade">
  <img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/2i9s4eb.jpg" />
  <p>text heading here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You're much more likely to get an answer if you a) explain which language you're using (and use a tag) and b) show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it correct from what you want, the easiest way to do this is use `position: absolute;` and `opacity` on `:hover` to achieve this. The positioning will set the layers on top of each other and not next to each other (as in your example).

See my example below.

```css
.container {
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;  /* Setting the boxes on top of each other */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;   /* Transition the opacity for the :hover */
}

.image-2 {
  background-position: bottom right;
  opacity: 0;
}

.image-1:hover .image-2 {
  opacity: 1;
}


/* Pure for styling below */

.box-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="box image-1">

    <div class="box image-2">

      <div class="box-text">

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, mollitia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim ipsa maxime modi velit similique maiores, porro voluptate? Molestias ratione natus consequatur libero eaque
          pariatur optio quisquam minima. Nemo quis, odit.
        </p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!